# using < and > with batch files (FIND command)

Tags: batch-file

I need to find a string having `< str >` inside it using windows `cmd.exe` `find` command, how can I do this?

Isn't `<` a reserved character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes (") around the argument to protect the special characters from processing by the shell.

Comment: You can also use ^ to escape occurrences of reserved characters (except %).

Answer (score 2):

< and > are reserved characters, but they don't have that meaning when they're inside `"pairs of double quotes"`.  Wrap your search string argument to `find` in double quotes and you'll be okay.